# Cs-Cart v3 fixed/static menu

Tags: php, smarty, 960.gs, cs-cart

I'm trying to see how this can be done in CS-Cart v3; I want the header or what is in the "top wrapper" (for instance "my account", "cart contents" and the menu) to remain fixed. Please refer to these website for the design intent.. http://studionudge.com/  & http://www.fullstopinteractive.com/ .

These are obviously not carts but it's the basic principle of the header being static or fixed.

If it can't be done within the smarty/960gs template could it be done outside with tpl calls done for the account and cart functions.

Thanks